# 画像データが無いときにImage Viewの分のスペースを詰めて表示するには？

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

下記画像のようなUIを作っています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

RatingとComment Textの間には画像がある場合と無い場合があり、画像が無いときに表示を詰めたいと考え、下記の処理をしているのですがうまくスペースを削除することができません。

よい方法がありましたらご教示くださいませ。

### やったこと

- Auto LayoutでComment Text（Text View）が画像（Image View）から1ピクセルになるように設定した⇒Top Space to: Image View Equals: 1
- この画面のView Controllerの`viewWillAppear`で、画像データが存在しないときには、Image Viewの高さが０になるようにした。

  ```
  if (!_image)
  {
      CGRect rect = CGRectMake(20,108,280,0); //新しいサイズを指定
      _thumImageView.frame = rect;
  }
  ```

Comment: 画像を見やすいサイズに調整してみました。アップロードされた画像のファイル名の最後 (かつ拡張子の前) にs/m/lの文字を付けるとサイズ調整ができます。

Comment: おお、そうなんですね！実は最初に画像をアップロードした時に、画像が大きくてびっくりしたので、解像度を下げて再度アップしてみたのですが表示サイズが変わらなかったので、スタックオーバーフローではこの大きさで表示されるものなんだ、と思ってました。わざわざ修正していただき、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageViewの高さについてどのようなConstraintを設定されているのか分かりませんが
もし、定数でHeightのConstraintを設定されているのであれば、そちらをIBOutletで接続し、constantの値を変更してください

```
@implementation ViewController 
{
    IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *_imageViewHeightConstraint;
}

- (void)viewWillApper
{
    [super viewWillAppear];

    if (!_image)
    {
        _imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0; // 高さを0にする制約を設定
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // ビューの再配置を実行
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: なるほど、contraintにIBOutletを接続することができるんですね！めでたく解決いたしました。ありがとうございました。